# Error:The following From address failed: mymailid@gmail.com

Tags: email, sugarcrm

I am trying to configure Email Settings --> Outgoing Mail Configuration.

I have filled below details:

--> "From" Name: SugarCRM

--> "From" Address: mymailid@gmail.com

I Selected 'Other' options: Enter details as below.

SMTP Mail Server: smtp.gmail.com
Use SMTP Authentication: Checked it
Username: mymailid@gmail.com
Password: ********

I tried below thinks:

SMTP Port: 25
Enable SMTP over SSL or TLS?: None

SMTP Port: 465
Enable SMTP over SSL or TLS?: SSL

SMTP Port: 25
Enable SMTP over SSL or TLS?: TLS

If i click on Send Test Email: Error:The following From address failed: mymailid@gmail.com.

What is the issue. how to fix this?